# fetch() function to get one single post, from a post array

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am following a tutorial and I wrote the following fetch() function when the instructor asked to try it on our own.

```js
const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/api/posts/";
const API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000/";

window.onload = () => {
    getPost();
    getPostIdParam()
}

const getPostIdParam=()=>{
    const queryString= window.location.search;
    const urlParams=new URLSearchParams(queryString)
    return urlParams.get("id")
    console.log(urlParams)
}

const getPost = () => 
    {
        fetch(API_URL,{
            method:'GET'
        }).then((response)=>{
            return response.json()
        }).then((data)=>{
            buildPost(data)
        })
    }
    

const buildPost = (data) => {

    let postId=getPostIdParam()
    let post= data.find(x =>x.id == postId)
     console.log("post title"+ JSON.stringify(post) )
     const postDate= new Date(parseInt(post.added_date)).toDateString()
     let postPrint=`
     <div id="individual-post-title">
            ${post.title}
     </div>
     <div id="individual-post-date">${postDate}</div>
     <div id="individual-post-content"> ${post.content}
     </div>
            `
            document.querySelector('.blog-inner').innerHTML
=postPrint


}
```

However the instructor's fetch() code look like this

```js
window.onload = () => {
    getPost();
    getPostIdParam()
}

const getPostIdParam=()=>{
    const queryString= window.location.search;
    const urlParams=new URLSearchParams(queryString)
    return urlParams.get("id")
}

const getPost = () => 
    {

        const postId=getPostIdParam()
        const url=`${API_URL}${postId}`

        fetch(url,{
            method:'GET'
        }).then((response)=>{
            return response.json()
        }).then((data)=>{
            buildPost(data)
        })
    }
```

Why is fetch(API_URL) and fetch(url) both working? Shouldn't one be wrong?

Comment: Without knowing the API definition, it looks like you're getting all posts and the instructor is specifying a post id in order to get one post.

Comment: Thanks Dilan, the API definition is set for both id and posts, so I was actually getting all the posts when I could have just fetched one post, its probably making the process slow,

Comment: That's literally what I said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you mean by both working? Actually, I assume both should work.
It seems like the instructor's way is making more sense. Because the instructor was trying to get one particular post using the post id.

But your way which means using `"http://localhost:3000/api/posts/"` should ideally return all posts.

So I guess there are two endpoints already to fetch all posts and one particular post. Therefore, both URLs are working.

Comment: yes thats right, both urls /endpoints are working, oh ok now i get it

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is wrong as postId is needed for fetch =>

> const url=`${API_URL}${postId}`

In instructor's code that is handled.

Comment: Yes it looked like it was unnecessary initialy, but realized we can just get one post instead of getting all the post on an individual post page, so probably better performance in the former